# Biblatex: Using "and" within textcite, "&" within parencite, "&" within bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am very new to LaTeX as you will see from my crude MWE.  I have spent a lot of time tweaking `biblatex` to how I need it to look.  I have one final problem, I can not find a work around and can't find a solution on the site.

I would like to show an "and" for my `\textcite` when there are multiple authors, which it currently does.  Although I would like to have "&" for my `\parencite` with multiple authors.  I would also like to have my bibliography showing "&".

Please find MWE and any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    uniquename=init,giveninits,giveninits=true, terseinits=true,hyperref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}%Surname first

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 %\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  %\addspace\&\space}

\newcommand{\biband}{\ifcurrentname{labelname}{\bibstring{and}}{\&}}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{4}{\finalandcomma}{}%
   \addspace\biband\space}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\addspace}%Sets comma
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%Sets commas


\setlength{\bibhang}{0em}%remove indent
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}% add vertical space

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author = "Family, Given and Second, A and Given, Two",
 title = "title",
 journal = "Journal",
 year = "2012"}

 @Article{leis2016,
  Title                    = {A Temperature Compensation Technique for Near-Infrared Methane Gas Threshold Detection},
  Author                   = {J. Leis and D. Buttsworth},
  Journal                  = {{IEEE} Trans. Ind. Electron.},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Month                    = mar,
  Number                   = {3},
  Pages                    = {1813--1821},
  Volume                   = {63},
  File                     = {ieeetie-2016.pdf:PDF},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


I would like to use {\bfseries ``\&''} within the {\bfseries bibliography}. \\
I would like to use {\bfseries ``and''} in {\bfseries textcite} \textcite{leis2016} \\ 
I would like to use {\bfseries ``\&''} within {\bfseries parencite} \parencite{leis2016}.\\

Example of three authors would be the same as above \textcite{test} using {\bfseries ``and''} within {\bfseries textcite}. \\

Although using {\bfseries parencite} to be {\bfseries ``\&''} \parencite{test}. 

\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{}{}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have just realised my MWE is not as a code.  I will try to rectify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Change of the final name delimiter between `\parencite` and `\textcite` from "&" to "and" as in
>
> > (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) and Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)
>
> is a feature of APA style. See for example https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/01/writing-in-text-citations-in-apa-style.html and https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/changes-parentheses-bring.html.
>
> If you are looking for a complete implementation of APA style with `biblatex`, you may be interested in [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa), which when loaded as
>
> ```
> \usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
> ```
>
> should produce a bibliography and citations according to APA guidelines.
>
> The answer below shows how to change the final name delimiter in the standard styles.

With the new context sensitive delimiter interface that should be as easy as redefining `finalnamdelim` in global scope to give an ampersand and to give "and" for `textcite`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,companion}

\parencite{sigfridsson,companion}

\textcite{sigfridsson,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson & Ryde 1998; Goossens, Mittelbach & Samarin 1994\(Sigfridsson & Ryde 1998; Goossens, Mittelbach & Samarin 1994)\Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) and Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin (1994)\Goossens, Michel, Frank Mittelbach & Alexander Samarin (1994).\Sigfridsson, Emma & Ulf Ryde (1998).]

*Edited to use the context sensitive delimiter interface. See the edit history for older versions of `biblatex`.*

Comment: Worked a charm!

Comment: I did try to upvote, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for it to show.

Answer (score 2):

Biblatex supports context-sensitive delimiters; i.e. depending on the citation command used (`\textcite`, `\parencite`, etc), you can tell biblatex to use a different delimiter, for certain delimiter types.  See §3.10.2 of the biblatex manual for more details.

`\finalnamedelim` is the delimiter used to separate (the last) two names in a citation or bibliography entry.  Unfortunately, `\finalnamedelim` is *not* context sensitive by default, but we can easily change that:

```
% Modify name:delim to use a context-sensitive version of finalnamedelim
\xpatchbibmacro{name:delim}
  {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}
  {\printdelim{finalnamedelim}}
  {}{}

% Set the global context to use an ampersand
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

% Set the textcite context specifically to use the "and" string
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

**How this works**

According to the biblatex documentation, `\finalnamedelim` is:

> The delimiter printed instead of \multinamedelim before the final name in
>   a name list. The default is the localised term ‘and’, separated by interword spaces.

It is defined in `biblatex.def` as:

```
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

Note that the implementation is different in Spanish.

In all the standard styles, it is called via the `name:delim` bibmacro, which also defined in `biblatex.def`:

```
\newcommand*{\lbx@finalnamedelim}[1]{\finalnamedelim}
\newbibmacro*{name:delim}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
     }
       {\multinamedelim}
       {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}
```

So, to make `name:delim` use a context sensitive version of `\finalnamedelim`, we need to use `\printdelim{finalnamedelim}` instead of `\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}`.  You could make a complete copy of `name:delim` and change only that line, or you can use the `xpatch` package to selectively replace only the part you care about:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{name:delim}
  {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}
  {\printdelim{finalnamedelim}}
  {}{}
```

The final step is to now declare the delimiter format for each context using `DeclareDelimFormat[<context>]{<name>}{<code>}`.

If you don't specify a context, then the format will apply globally (i.e. to any context that doesn't have a specific format set).  Hence, the following will force an ampersand to be used for all contexts unless otherwise specified:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}
```

And now we override the `\textcite` context:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

`\bibstring{and}` keeps this language sensitive, and also allows you to override it with:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  and = {as well as}%
}
```

*Note:*

The format definition for the `\textcite` context is just the original definition of `\finalnamedelim`.  You might therefore be tempted to try to simply it:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{\finalnamedelim}
```

What this actually does is use our format definition for the global context, and so you will get an ampersand, not `\bibstring{and}`.  Incidentally, that is why you can't do this:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\finalnamedelim}
```

This will send the compiler into an infinite recursion, and it will eventually crash.

Comment: Very nice solution and explanation. Indeed there are quite some delimiters that don't use the new `\printdelim` features yet. Maybe some more should do so by default.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm not sure why the standard list of context-sensitive options is so limited; it concerned me that maybe there was a good reason that I had overlooked, given the apparent simplicity of making it work... Hopefully it's only because no one has had time yet to expand support for it.

Comment: When the feature was developed (not very long ago) it was for quite a specific reason ([`biblatex` issue #373](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/373)). It was then expanded to the bibliography (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/26a9d05ade70a650d6a20a47d27c1f9eed53f74b and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/86ceff2f7f84d20c1dbeae7c65ee6df2287e1bf9). But then we didn't go any further. The system is quite sophisticated, but changes to code that has been there for quite a long time is always risky. Any suggestions and requests for new delimiters to be added are welcome...

Comment: ... just drop by https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. Or if you already have an idea, submit a pull request.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm still fairly new to biblatex (latex in general, really), but I'll certainly have a look at that.