# Shortauthor and authoryear-icomp: Use full author name for first citation like apa style

Tags: biblatex, authoryear-icomp

I am using the `authoryear-icomp` biblatex style. For some publications by institutions with long names, I would like to use `shortauthor`. However, the style `authoryear-icomp` simply uses `shortauthor` from the first citation onwards, like so:

[image]

I would like it to work as it does in `style=apa`, which uses the full author name for the first citation and introduces the short name in square brackets, which it then uses for all further citations (even for other publications of the same author).

This is the output if I change the style to `apa`:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour with `authoryear-icomp`?

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, % alternatively: style=apa
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  autocite=inline,
  backend=biber
  ]
 {biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}

@online{test1,
  author = {{Institution Long Name}},
  shortauthor = {ILN},
  title = {Test title},
  year = {2020}
}

@online{test2,
  author = {{Institution Long Name}},
  shortauthor = {ILN},
  title = {Another test title},
  year = {2020}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}


\begin{document}

Citation number one \autocite{test1}.

Citation number two \autocite{test1}.

Third citation with a different publication by the same author \autocite{test2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449052/35864.

Comment: I made sure my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449052/35864 works again and I checked that it also works with `style=authoryear-icomp,`. So I suggest you check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449082/35864 because as I understand it your question is pretty much answered by the solution there.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to try it yet, but from what I understand of the code, it uses the `author` field and divides it in long and short name parts. My whole bib file, however, uses the `shortauthor` field, so I imagine it would not work 'out of the box' without adapting my bib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this - I took some code from APA style. You may need to make this more in line with `cite` from the `authoryear-icomp` style for more general use but this gets you what you want as a start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, % alternatively: style=apa
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  autocite=inline,
  backend=biber
  ]
 {biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testbib.bib}

@online{test1,
  author = {{Institution Long Name}},
  shortauthor = {ILN},
  title = {Test title},
  year = {2020}
}

@online{test2,
  author = {{Institution Long Name}},
  shortauthor = {ILN},
  title = {Another test title},
  year = {2020}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{metacite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:post}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{fullhash}}{\cbx@names}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\cbx@names}{\thefield{fullhash}}}}

\global\let\cbx@names\@empty
\def\cbx@ifnamesaved{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{fullhash}}{\cbx@names}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\newbibmacro*{metacite}{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {\usebibmacro{cite}}
    {\usebibmacro{sacite}}}

\newbibmacro*{sacite}{%
  \cbx@ifnamesaved
    {\printnames{shortauthor}}
    {\printnames{author}%
     \addspace\mkbibbrackets{\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Citation number one \autocite{test1}.

Citation number two \autocite{test1}.

Third citation with a different publication by the same author \autocite{test2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great for the initial citation! I just realized, however, that the subsequent citations only show `shortauthor` and not the year (e.g., "2020b") --- which is probably what you referred to when you said further adjustments might be necessary. I've taken a long look at the cbx file, but have to admit I'm rather overwhelmed. Could you point me to where to go from here?

Comment: My mistake - I have corrected the `sacite` macro above.