# Using initials for certain authors and full name in the reference list

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a document and using `biblatex` with APA style for my references. Due to space constraints in my document, I want to use the initials of certain authors (mainly academies and institutes) but I still want to provide the full name in the reference list. An in-text citation could look like this:

> AVL (2006)

And the reference list would look like this:

> AVL = Acadèmia Valenciana de la Llengua. (2006). *Gramàtica normativa valenciana*. Acadèmia Valenciana de la Llengua.

What I am using now is this:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,sortlocale=nb_NO,
sortcites,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shortened institutional authors you can use the `shortauthor` field.

APA style requires that the full name be given in the first citation along with the abbreviation. In subsequent citations the abbreviation is used. The bibliography lists only the full name.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{avl,
  author      = {{Acadèmia Valenciana de la Llengua}},
  shortauthor = {AVL},
  title       = {Gramàtica normativa valenciana},
  year        = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{avl}
ipsum \autocite{avl}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Acadèmia Valenciana de la Llengua [AVL], 2006) ipsum (AVL, 2006)//Acadèmia Valenciana de la Llengua. (2006). Gramàtica normativa valenciana.]

If you do not like the way APA style handles this I strongly recommend you do *not* use `biblatex-apa` since you are losing APA compliance anyway. Go for the standard `authoryear` style instead. In that case [Biblatex: long author names in first citation followed by shortnames thereafter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449052/35864) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you! These references will most likely only appear in tables and that's why I do not have enough space. I don't want them to look different in the first table compared to the others. I may change my mind later on but for now I prefer what I posted in the question (or any solution that makes them look short and the same).

Comment: There is `\makeatletter
\let\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved\@firstoftwo
\makeatother`, but then you'd still have to work with the bibliography.